# Detect multiple use of an IP address

Tags: c#, networking

I'm using the [ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) class to ping a range of IPs to detect the up  running IPs in the network 192.168.1.0 - 255

I got responses from: 
 
- 192.168.1.1 (router) 
 
- 192.168.1.11 (device a) 
 
- 192.168.1.23 (device b) 
 
- 192.168.1.22 (device c)

**device c**  is a virtual machine (Bridge mode )

I'm using [Xerosploit](https://github.com/LionSec/xerosploit) to spoof over the network in the device c

I can clearly detect a duplicate use of 192.168.1.1 using Wireshark, is there any trick to detect the duplicate use of an IP address in .NET using c#?

Can we consider an IP address different than the router IP address calling Arp request a sign of IP spoofing?

Comment: If you can access the MAC address from a PingReply then any IP address with two MAC addresses indicates a spoofed address (or a poorly configured network).  Regarding the question "can we consider an IP adress different than the router ip adress calling Arp request a sign of ip spoofing ?" I'd so no, because there isn't anything wrong with a device calling ARP requests. It seems pretty normal.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner unfortunately PingReply class wich gives a reply of the ping i send does not have any method that provides you with the mac adress information ,  and in my case i cannot use a hidden prompt to check the Arp cache

Comment: Then you have a problem. IP is a layer-3 protocol, and that seems to be what you are using. You would need to be able to compare the layer-3 and layer-2 (MAC) addressing.

Comment: @RonMaupin can you please clarify more please

Comment: The only way to know if multiple devices are assigned the same IP address is to compare something unique about the device(s) assigned the IP address. That would be something like the MAC address. ARP is what relates a layer-3 to a layer-2 address.